# I want to INSERT multiple array values into the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Array
(
    [subject] => Mathematics
    [admissionno] => Array
        (
            [0] => MS3389
            [1] => MS3387
            [2] => MS3384
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Abdulbasit Alaka-Yusuf
            [1] => Abdulbasit Alaka-Yusuf
            [2] => Abdulbasit Alaka-Yusuf
        )

    [ca] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 14
            [2] => 17
        )

    [assignment] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 18
        )

    [exam] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 19
        )

    [comment] => Array
        (
            [0] => qwerty
            [1] => asdfghj
            [2] => fghjcfb 
        )

    [save] => 
)
```

I'm trying to insert this array into the database
this is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        $id      = isset($_POST['id'])   && $_POST['id'] != ''   ? $_POST['id']  :   "";
        $subject = isset($_POST['subject'])    && $_POST['subject']    != "" ? $_POST['subject']        : "";
        $admissionno = isset($_POST['admissionno'])    && $_POST['admissionno']    != "" ? $_POST['admissionno']        : "";
        $name = isset($_POST['name'])    && $_POST['name']    != "" ? $_POST['name']        : "";
        $ca = isset($_POST['ca'])    && $_POST['ca']    != "" ? $_POST['ca']        : "";
        $assignment = isset($_POST['assignment'])    && $_POST['assignment']    != "" ? $_POST['assignment']        : "";
        $exam = isset($_POST['exam'])    && $_POST['exam']    != "" ? $_POST['exam']        : "";
        $comment = isset($_POST['comment'])    && $_POST['comment']    != "" ? $_POST['comment']        : "";

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r ($_POST);//die();

        $admissionno = implode("','",$_POST['admissionno']);
        $name = implode("','",$_POST['name']);
        $ca = implode("','",$_POST['ca']);
        $assignment = implode("','",$_POST['assignment']);
        $exam = implode("','",$_POST['exam']);
        $comment = implode("','",$_POST['comment']);
        //echo $admissionno. $name. $ca. $assignment. $exam. $comment;

        $insert_qry = "INSERT INTO result (id,subject, admissionno, name, ca, assignment, exam, comment)
                       VALUES('$id', '$subject', '$admissionno', '$name', '$ca', '$assignment', '$exam', '$comment')";
        echo $insert_qry;
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $insert_qry);
        die('e don do oo');

        if($result > 0){
            
        }
    }
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Malizzay\admin\exam\exam-grade.php:37
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Malizzay\admin\exam\exam-grade.php(37): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO res...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Malizzay\admin\exam\exam-grade.php on line 37
```

Comment: You can't insert all the rows in a single `VALUES` list. You need `VALUES (values for row 1), (values for row 2), (values for row3)`.

Comment: Output the query and the issue should be clear. If you want multiple rows the syntax is `values (row1), (row2),(row3)` not `values(row1, row2,row3)` as it appears you currently have. If you are attempting to store data as CSV in column you also should not do that.

Comment: And your code isn't even generating `values (row1, row2, row3)`. It's generating `values (all ids, all subjects, all admissionno, ...)`

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Comment: carefully about sql injection in your sql,

Comment: How do generate the values for each row @barmar

Comment: Do you mean I should do a for loop when I want to INSERT @user3783243

Comment: `isset($_POST['id'])   && $_POST['id'] != ''` is `!empty($_POST['id'])`

Comment: Related (but answers are not necessarily advisable): https://stackoverflow.com/q/23526198/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/7320512/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/11720981/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/53968999/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/11301871/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/45871981/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to insert all the values at once, use a loop. Prepare the `INSERT` statement with parameters before the loop, then reassign the variables in the loop to the current iteration in all the `POST` parameters.

There's no `id` in the form, so you don't need to use `$id`. That's presumably an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, so you leave it out of the `INSERT` and it will be inserted automatically.

```
$insert_stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "
    INSERT INTO result (subject, admissionno, name, ca, assignment, exam, comment)
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert_stmt, "sssssss", $subject, $admissionno, $name, $ca, $assignment, $exam, $comment);
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
foreach ($_POST['admissionno'] as $i => $admissionno) {
    $name = $_POST['name'][$i];
    $ca = $_POST['ca'][$i];
    $assignment = $_POST['assignment'][$i];
    $exam = $_POST['exam'][$i];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'][$i];
    mysqli_stmt_execute($insert_stmt);
}
```

Comment: Please can you write it in a simple code?

Comment: How can I make this any simpler?

Comment: i got this error

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "as", expecting ";"

Comment: Sorry, `for` should be `foreach`

Comment: i mean to write it in procedural way

Comment: OK, I rewrote it. But the the OO way is simpler IMHO. The documentation shows the correspondence.

Comment: Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Malizzay\admin\exam\exam-grade.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Malizzay\admin\exam\exam-grade.php(33): mysqli->prepare('\r\n        INSER...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Malizzay\admin\exam\exam-grade.php on line 33

Comment: Sorry. WHen I removed `id` from the column list I forgot to remove its `?` from the `VALUES` list.

Comment: I feel like in 2022, we probably have tens of Stack Overflow pages that demonstrate the necessary approach.  Does this need to be answered to be resolved?

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm really getting tired of you criticizing me for not finding a dup when you don't provide one, either.

Comment: I am fully busy consolidating the last decade of redundant php page.  This is my excuse for not voting to close THIS page.  I only came upon this page today, because it was in the search results while I was trying to close another page.  It is not solely my job to find duplicates.  I have a full time job and family and I need to sleep.  I cannot possibly close every new duplicate.  I am hoping that the veteran PHP contributors here will have enough good will to close new basic duplicates when they are asked. I am targeting a specific topic. My current progress: https://3v4l.org/CtE2W

Comment: Okay I've added links to 7 other related pages and hammered this page closed, but my point is that Stack Overflow needs your persistent help to help consolidate the redundant content so that this place can be the researchers' paradise that it was designed to be.